# Tags: Mash and Mashing

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

Mashing seems to be a duplicate/sub-set of Mash.

I suggest removal of 'mashing' and to re-tag the questions 'mash' before removal.

Answer (score 4):

Seems reasonable. I recommend merging [mashing](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mashing) into [mash](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mash) and creating a synonym in the process - this'll result in less confusion on down the road.